# Aircon cold enough only when weather is cold?

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a weird condition here.

If average weather temperature outside is 30 (86 Fahrenheit) in whole day (8am - midnight), my room will be quite hot, even I set my aircon in fan 2 - 18 degree.

While, if the average temperature is around 26 (79F), my room will be cold enough in fan 1 - 24, or even 25 (77F), degree.

What could be wrong in my aircon? Usually I turn on the aircon after go back from work - going to go to work next day.

Comment: Loss of coolant?

Comment: Not so sure. The aircon still breathes out cold wind, but not cold enough for my room. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand this, as sometimes numbers are degrees C, and other times fan settings. Making this clearer would help us give you a good answer.

Comment: The A/C is weak, probably due to loss of coolant or very clogged coils.

Comment: @DanielGriscom: Sorry since here using degrees C for temperature, hope Harper's edit can make it clearer.

Comment: @Harper: I am also not sure with clogged coils, since on early May, my aircon just got vacuum, although not cleaned by water/chemical. Thanks for your edit by the way.

Comment: Cold- but not cold enough for your room- usually means either coolant loss or inadequate size; test it. Turn it on max-high and let it run for 5 minutes. Hold a thermometer in front of the vent. The temperature coming out of the vent should be 8 - 12 °C cooler than the temperature in the room. If not, you probably need coolant. If it is working well, then the size of the AC is too small for your living space, and you need an AC with higher capacity. Also possible is the thermocouple is reading too cold, so the compressor is cutting off. If the thermocouple is too close to the coil separate it.

Answer (score 1):

A non acid foaming coil cleaner on the outside condensing unit will work much better than vacuuming. If you can see light through the fins this may not be needed and a service call to fill the system may be needed. If low on freon the tech may be able to find the leak. Many times on older units the service port caps get loose and need some sealer on the threads after a recharge.